# Тестирование состояния react компонента Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jest

Как достать состояние компонента для того, чтобы проверить его?
Все примеры в доках https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html только с функциональными компонентами, а с классами ничего. Можно ли проверять состояние?